# Operator not followed by a character

Tags: excel, vba, operator-keyword

I am using the find and replace function and a vba code in Excel. I want to replace all strings like "/15" by ".15" but only if "/15" is not followed by any other characters. Is there an operator for my need?

For example if I replace all "/15" it also replaces this string if it is followed by other characters.

10/15/15 -> 10.15.15

But what I want is

10/15/15 -> 10/15.15

Cheers

Comment: Please can you add an example input string, or is xx/xx/xx the full input string to look at?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions, a wealth of stuff on the net about that.

Or something in VBA like so, no real need for a2, could grab the last of a1 before hand, but just to show you difference in the arrays in the locals window.

```
Function test(strInput As String)

Dim a1() As String
Dim a2() As String

a1 = Split(strInput, "/")
a2 = a1

ReDim Preserve a2(UBound(a1) - 1)

test = Join(a2, "/") & "." & a1(UBound(a1))

End Function
```

or it can be done using a formula

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",".",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))`

Comment: This will replace slashes also in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the function Right for this, to avoid replacing the "/15" in the middle of the string.

```
Public Function ReplaceRight(strInput As String) As String
    If Right(strInput, 3) = "/15" Then
        ReplaceRight = Left(strInput, Len(strInput) - 3) & ".15"
    Else
        ReplaceRight = strInput
    End If
End Function
```

With Excel Formula:

```
=IF(RIGHT(F215,3)="/15",LEFT(F215,LEN(F215)-3)&".15",F215)
```